# Is get_field_id() Necessary for Form Filed in WordPress Widget API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a custom widget for my plugin and following [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

This is what I have so far. It's working and saves and displays the saved option value.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Sample Widget
 */

$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow');
update_option('sample_widget', $colors);

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Sample_Widget" );' ) );
class Sample_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', 
            'Sample Widget', 
            array( 'description' => __( 'This is a description of the sample widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $color = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['color'] );

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        echo 'the selected color is ' . $color . '<br />';
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['color'] = $new_instance['color'];
        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        }
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'color' ] ) ) {
            $selected_color = $instance[ 'color' ];
        }
        $colors = get_option('sample_widget');
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'color' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <?php foreach($colors as $color) echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $color ) . '" ' . ($color == $selected_color ? 'selected="Selected"' : '') .  '>'. $color .'</option>'; ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php 
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What is `id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>"` for? I removed this part of the line and it seems to work fine. I placed it to just copy the codex working code.
2. In the constructor, the first parameter in `parent::__construct()` is a base ID. Could this be any string value? I changed it to something else from `foo_widget` and it seems to work.

Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>"` is to generate a unique 'id' value for this option.  Typically this is so the object can be manipulated via JS.
2. The `id_base` of `foo_widget` is a Root id for all widgets of this type. It is an Optional Base ID for the widget, in lower case, and if left empty a portion of the widget's class name will be used. It has to be unique. This will be appended to with the individual widget's ID number i.e.`foo_widget-001`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Regarding #1, it sounds like I'd better leave it as it is. Thanks for your input. As for #2, I changed the base ID to something else like `something_else` from `foo_widget` and I used the string value `Sample_Widget` in `create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Sample_Widget" );' )` and it still works. So it seems they can be different values. Am I missing something?

Comment: Based on what I know of the subject and some limited database browsing... I'm wondering if this second instance of the 'base ID' is what WordPress uses to create the database table to store the widget info. If you go to the 'WP_Options' table you will see things like 'widget_categories' or 'widget_text'.  I'm assuming that your active widgets will appear as 'widget_Sample_Widget" in the datbase?  Just a thought

Comment: I found that the parameter value for `register_widget()` is the extended custom class name. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget So it should be a different thing from base ID. When I browsed the `wp_options` table, indeed I found an element named, `widget_someting_else`; it wasn't 'widget_Sample_Widget'. So at this point, I feel more certain that the base ID can be any arbitrary string within the character length limitation for the option table. As far as I remember it was up to 45 characters or so.

Comment: Great! Please mark your question as 'answered' so others can learn from this as well!

Comment: In that case, could you update your answer since the following statement turned out to be not true: `The base id of foo_widget is what you would use to register the widget: // register Foo_Widget widget add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "foo_widget" );' ) );`? Thanks.

Comment: Found more info and update your answer.  Hope this takes care of it all now!